# iOS programmatically change all default colours

Tags: ios, swift

This code in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions()

```
window?.tintColor = .red  
window?.backgroundColor = .green
```

change the default views *tint color*, not the background color, of my whole application, which is a double view with table view.
The default *text color* is a black "Color Dark Text" in label texts, and a black "Color default" in text fields.

Is there a way to programmatically change all the defaults color, foreground and background?

Comment: Save color codes somewhere global and then change the color via sending notification observer and post notification and it will change all colors in notification observer selector.

Comment: Thanks Zulqarnain.
Could you write an example do let me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via appearance. E.g. to change backround color of every view:
`UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green`

Note: If you change background of some view, appearance will not apply.

Comment: Thanks Luzo. It works on almost any elements, so few remains to be changed.
Do you know how to set the default color for text?

Comment: Same pattern UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.red. Don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: And UITextField.appearance().textColor !
Thanks Luzo